# How do I iterate over a hashset of dictionaries

Tags: c#

Apologies in advance; I am on day 3 of trying to learn C#.

I am instructed to build a hashset of dictionaries; no problem. I see that that has been built. I now need to iterate over the hashset and copy the entries to a new list if the dictionary's key != a particular string. Could someone kindly explain the proper syntax for achieving this seemingly simple task?

```
var goodSongs = new List<Dictionary<string,string>>();

var allSongs = new HashSet<Dictionary<string, string>>();

Dictionary<string, string> meatloaf = new Dictionary<string, string>();
meatloaf.Add("Meatloaf", "Paradise By The Dashboard Light");

Dictionary<string, string> aerosmith = new Dictionary<string,string>();
aerosmith.Add("Aerosmith", "Cryin'");

Dictionary<string, string> nickelback = new Dictionary<string, string>();
nickelback.Add("Nickelback", "Rockstar");

allSongs.Add(nickelback);
allSongs.Add(aerosmith);
allSongs.Add(meatloaf);

//foreach loop to iterate dictionaries goes here
```

Goal - To get unstuck, hope to learn C#, and decide if I want to keep going down this rabbit hole. Thanks to all.

Comment: Can you more clearly specify the desired end result?

Comment: Sure, the end result is to add the dictionaries that do not have "Nickelback" as their key to the goodSongs list of dictionaries.

Comment: You can simply assume that the Dictionary is a list of key-value pairs. You use the dictionary as a single key-value pair for each song. Can you elaborate on your example?

Comment: You've mentioned foreach, have you tried it?

Comment: fyi, this will only do a hash based on the reference, not equality.

Comment: I have tried to write a foreach loop to go over the dictionaries, something along the lines of ```foreach (dictionary song in allsongs)...``` but I keep getting errors and have not been able to progress beyond that point.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but it occurs to me that your `goodSongs` should be `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>`, or possibly just `List<string>`, and not a list of dictionaries.  It's unclear to me what the purpose of the `HashSet` is, too.

Comment: The whole exercise is to familiarize our group with hashsets; that they will only store unique values and so forth. The exercise seems a bit contrived to me as well, as I think the same result could have been done with KeyValye Pairs, but the above is what I was tasked with.

Comment: This is a strange use of dictionaries; normally a dictionary would have more than one key-value pair in it. Why is this a set of dictionaries, and not either a single dictionary, or a set of pairs?

Comment: @eric; these are good questions! I had my own about this exercise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of how to iterate through the hashset and then the dictionary:

```
        var all = new HashSet<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        Dictionary<string, string> newDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        newDict.Add("M", "T");
        all.Add(newDict);

        foreach(Dictionary<string,string> dict in all)
        {
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> pair in dict)
            {
                string key = pair.Key;
                string value = pair.Value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: To complete the exercise, I added the following code ```if (pair.Key != "Nickelback") {
                            goodSongs.Add(song);
                        }``` Thank you for your help!